# Working with name.com API (PHP) Phase 2

Tags: php, arrays, dns, element

I've opened before a question about name.com API and got helpful answers.

Now, I come again with another question, Question is about listing domain names:

I want to get the info out of multidimensional arrays, What I've done so far is this:

```
$api = new NameComApi();
$api->username('XXX');
$api->apiToken('XXXXXXXXX');
$response = $api->list_domains();

foreach($response->domains as $Domains){
    echo "<ul>"
    ."<li>Creation date = {$Domains->create_date}"
    ."<li>Expiring date = {$Domains->expire_date}"
    ."</ul>";
}
```

This was successful, But what I wasn't successful in is to get the domain name :(

You can find the array below:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 100
            [message] => Command Successful
        )

    [domains] => stdClass Object
        (
            [XXXXXXX.com] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tld] => com
                    [create_date] => 2007-08-21 19:37:59
                    [expire_date] => 2013-08-22 01:37:59
                    [addons] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [whois_privacy] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [price] => 3.99
                                )

                            [domain/renew] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [price] => 10.99
                                )

                        )

                )
```

What I've been tried to far:

```
$Domains->domains
$Domains->domains[1]
$Domains->domains[]
```

But no luck, I know that I'm missing something important but I don't know what it is.

Waiting your reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(array_keys((array) $response->domains));
```

Or (because you iterate over the result anyway

```
foreach((array) $response->domains as $name => $domain) { /* code */ }
```

Comment: Done! Thank you.

Full code:
    foreach($response->domains as $name => $Domains){
     echo "<ul>"
     ."<li>Domain Name = {$name}"
     ."<li>Creation date = {$Domains->create_date}"
     ."<li>Expiring date = {$Domains->expire_date}"
     ."</ul>";
    }



Why is that? Could you please explain?

Comment: Another question please if you don't mind:

I can't get the price out of this array `[domain/renew]` because of the '/' How can I fix it?

Comment: See http://php.net/control-structures.foreach. When you cast an object to an array PHP will take the properties as the keys of the (associative) array. `foreach` with an object automatically casts it to an array. // `$foo = (array) $bar; echo $bar['domain/renew');` Would be easier, the API would return arrays instead of objects ...

Comment: Error:
{$Domains->addons->['domain/renew']}

Comment: I've read it, You see the array? I want to get out the price from it, Price is inside the addons array that inside the domains array

Comment: In your last comment you don't cast anything to an array (and neither `$Domains` itself, nor `$Domains->addons` are arrays).

Comment: Hello,

Please look at the main code, You will see that price is inside two arrays. I can't echo it because of / as I'm using this way {$Domains->create_date}

Comment: Please look at your "main code": There is absolutely no array, but only objects of type `stdClass`. This is the reason something like `$Domains->create_date` even works, because arrays are accessed like `$Domains['create_date']`. Now read the existing comments, the php manual (and so on).

Comment: When I do this:
var_dump($Domains->addons);

I got this:
object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["whois_privacy"]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) { ["price"]=> string(4) "3.99" } ["domain/renew"]=> object(stdClass)#10 (1) { ["price"]=> string(5) "10.99" } } xxxxxx.com

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've done it in this way:

echo $Domains->addons->{'domain/renew'}->price;